# How to use GetNativeSystemInfo in a Qt console application

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I'm trying to use the GetNativeSystemInfo api to get the architecture of the operating system(if it is a 32bit or a 64bit OS) but when i try to compile the code i get this error: 'GetNativeSystemInfo' was not declared in this scope, what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    _SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    GetNativeSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
    if (sysinfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL)
    {
        qDebug() << "win32";
    }
    if (sysinfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64)
    {
        qDebug() << "win64";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you may find the macros in [QtGlobal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html) or the functions in [QSysInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsysinfo.html) to be of help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code to get the system architecture using QtGlobal or QSysinfo?

Comment: Actually, looking more closely, Qt doesn't provide quite the same information as what you're looking for. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with `_WIN32_WINNT` defined to `0x0501` or above.

Either `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`, or use an appropriate compiler option (`/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` for msvc).

See more at [Using the Windows Headers (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: After add #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 to my code i get some errors: warning: "_WIN32_WINNT" redefined and the 'GetNativeSystemInfo' was not declared in this scope

Comment: I've forgot to tell, this `#define` should be before all `#include`s.